# how to correctly modify integers with while loops

Tags: java, while-loop, integer, greatest-common-divisor

So basically, I'm just trying to return a GCD from two previous numbers,

```
public static String GCD( int Denominator,int Numerator) {
    int newNum=Numerator;
    int newDen=Denominator;
    int newWhole=Whole;
    int GCD=0;
    if (Numerator == 0) {
        GCD = Denominator;
    }

    while (Denominator != 0) {
        if (Numerator > Denominator) {
            Numerator = Numerator - Denominator;
        }else {
            Denominator = Denominator - Numerator;
        }
    }
    GCD = Denominator;
    System.out.println(GCD);
}
```

You would think that since i declared GCD outside the loop that it would return just fine

but no, i just get 0 as an answer? almost every time..... thoughts?

Comment: I suspect your GCD algorithm is off.  For one thing, you never actually check if the steps you take result in a denominator which divides both numbers.  Speaking of which, I don't even see two numerators in the input.

Answer (score 0):

That's because your while loop is dependent on the value of `Denominator` as the loop ends when the value of Denominator is decreased to 0.

And right outside the while loop, you're storing the value of Denominator in `'GCD'` which is obviously '0'.

So no matter what you do in the while loop, you would get 0 as the final result of your GCD.

I hope this solves your problem.

Comment: any thoughts on how you would fix that? possibly look back one iteration of the while loop?

Answer (score 0):

You need a return statement somewhere in your code.  Probably at the end of the method, you need to write `return GCD;`.